# JAX-RS: Can I have entity (resource) that will be both resource and sub-resource?

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jpa, jax-rs, restful-architecture

I consider how to design my RESTful web service in JAX-RS and I have encounter some problem. 
I have Provider that has ServicePoints and more over ServicePoint entity has composite key consisting of provider_id and service_point_no. So logical seems to have:

```
/providers/1/service-points/3
```

But I would also have the ability to retrieve service points independently of Provider to get all Service Points in given location for instance.

```
/service-points // all 
/service-points?location=CountryName
```

But in the first approach I will have:

```
@Path("/") 
class ServicePointResource { /* ... */ }
```

Of course I can define it in many ways to workround this situation like have:

```
@Path("/providers") 
class Provider { 

    @Path("/{providerId}/service-points")
    public ServicePointResource getServicePointResource() { } 

     @Path("/")
     class ServicePointResource { 
          // here implemented subresource sepcific code 
     } 

} 

@Path("/service-points")
class ServicePointResource { 
   // here emplemented resource sepcific code 
 }
```

or just have:

```
@Path("/") 
class ProviderServicePointResource { 
  // here subresource specific code
} 

 @Path("/service-points")
 class ServicePointResource {
  // here resource specific code 
 }
```

Subresource approach seems to be natural but using ServicePoint just as global Resource to access it in some cases without Provider demarcation seems also important. 
I also could use here:

```
/service-points/1+3  // to represent composite key 
/providers/1/service-points/3 // but it seems more natural
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

If you think that service-point is major resource and provider is minor you could use

```
/service-point/id // service point by id
/service-point?provider=id // all service point of provider
```

Also you can use matrix params like this

```
/service-point;id=x;provider=y
```

This way you can combine any number of params.
If you consider service point and provider both major resources I would leave both paths:

```
/service-point/id
/provider/id1/service-point/
/provider/id1/service-point/id2
```

Comment: I think service point is sub resource of provider by nature as service point is weak entity i.e. inherits its part of composite key from provider as provider id + service point no.... But I see some occasions when I need to access service point independently like when searching it by location (address) rather than given specific provider

Comment: Than I would stick to my latest example. Maybe you'll even provide /service-point/id/provider